# WSO2: RabbitMQ AMQP Transport consumer proxy using Integration Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

**What is the best way to inject runtime AMQP Transport configuration to consume message using Integration Studio.**

Basically, I am creating an ESB rabbitMQ consumer artefacts using Integration studio, What I am looking for, run and test the application using Integration studio before creating artefacts. I want to change in runtime axis2.xml

/IntegrationStudio/runtime/microesb/conf/axis2.xml

Every time I change it Manually it gets back to the default stage.

Is it possible to change the value in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not descriptive enough. But what I understand is you have a running EI server and you need to modify the axis2.xml using the Integration studio.

The simple answer is no you cant modify the axis2.xml of an EI server using the Integration studio. The Integration studio is used to develop artifacts and can also be used to test the artifacts. But it is not developed to manage deployment configurations.

**Update**

The latest version of the Integration studio contains a micro integrator. For the micro integrator, we have introduced a config file deployment.toml (available in the conf directory) to make the configuration changes. At the start of the server, it will check for any changes in the deployment.toml and if there are no changes it will revert all the configurations.

Therefore you need to add the configurations in the deployment.toml instead of the axis2.xml file.

Refer to the following sample configuration and refer to the documentation [1] for more information regarding the configurations of the deployment.toml

```
[[transport.rabbitmq.listener]]
name = "AMQPConnectionFactory"
parameter.hostname = "localhost"
parameter.port = 5672
parameter.username = "guest"
parameter.password = "guest"
```

[1]-https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/setup/brokers/configure-with-rabbitMQ/

Comment: Thank you @Shanaka Premarathna


Basically, I am creating an ESB rabbitMQ consumer artefacts using Integration studio, What I am looking for, run and test the application using Integration studio before creating artefacts. I want to change in runtime axis2.xml

/IntegrationStudio/runtime/microesb/conf/axis2.xml

Every time I change it Manually it gets back to the default stage.

Is it possible to change the value in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782297/wso2-rabbitmq-amqp-transport-consumer-proxy-using-integration-studio/64782583#64782583) answer, WSO2 Micro Integrator uses deployment.toml to manage configurations, and Integration Studio 7.1.0 has Micro Integrator 1.2.0 (at /IntegrationStudio/runtime/microesb) as its embedded server.

We have to use the **Embedded Micro Integrator Configuration** option in the Integration Studio (7.1.0) to apply changes to the embedded server, as described [here](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/develop/using-embedded-micro-integrator/#update-embedded-server-configs-and-libraries). Manual editing on server files will be replaced with the values shown in the 'Embedded Micro Integrator Configuration' wizard.

Comment: Thank you @prabushi, I change the value in deployment.toml but unfortunately it is not working. Also, I noticed there is no way, I can receive full incoming header from RabbitMQ as JSON (if I am not missing anything).